# Run a Command doesn't do anything 

Tags: command-line

After I press alt + f2 the window for "Run a command comes up" after that I specifically type in a command and then select or enter the command and nothing happens, it is suppose to ask me to type in my password and the window to open but absolutely nothing happens, please help me as this is the only way I can iron out the creases on Linux and if this doesn't work then nothing would work properly.

Comment: What is the command? Have you tried to launch it from terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type your command with gksu before like this : gksu MyCommand

For having better control of what happens run your command from a terminal. Graphical ways is always hidding many things.

Answer (score 1):

It probably carried the command out, you're just not aware of it yet.

If the command begins with "sudo" substitute "gksu" for the sudo command so that you get a visual password prompt to carry the command out.